# With VirtualBox installed, establishing wifi connection is slow even after disabling Host-Only Network adapter

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

After installing VirtualBox, I noticed that my computer (Windows 7) was taking an unusually long time to establish a wifi connection on startup.
I found this "trick" and I tried it:
http://scottiestech.info/2010/12/31/fix-slow-windows-networking-problems-when-virtualbox-is-installed/

Disabling the Host-Only Network adapter did nothing. On further reboot, it was still taking close to a full minute to get onto my wifi network.

To confirm that this was VirtualBox-related, I completely uninstalled VirtualBox from my machine.  After uninstalling and rebooting, my wifi connection instantly connected.

Are there any other things I can try, besides Disabling the Host-Only Network Adapter, to fix this problem?

Comment: I have even tried installing Virtualbox without including the Host-Only Networking option at all. Still the same problem.

Comment: Also, possibly relevant, when I install Virtualbox, my "Virtual Wifi Miniport" adapters disappear.

Comment: OK.. if I also don't install the Bridged Networking option, then I can get the machine to boot up and connect to wifi properly.. and all of the VMs' networking functionality works too (behind NAT).  I guess I've answered another of my own questions.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem. Much simpler fix was, via Network and Sharing Center, to change Wifi Adapter settings. Simply uncheck "Virtual Box bridged newrok adapter" in Networking tab, and your wifi will establish connection within seconds, not minutes. Whenever you need bridged networking via wifi card for your Virtual Box, you can check it back. Meanwhile, bridged networking still works on your wired NIC.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Had the problem trying out Docker on Windows...

Answer (score 3):

Yup, just for people who find this question in the future: I did end up solving this myself by installing VirtualBox with *all* of the networking options disabled. Using NAT still seems to be working fine for my purposes. 
If I ever find the need to use the Bridged or Host-Only networks, I will revisit this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that works, but that is not the proper fix (at least on Windows 7). The host only is needed for shared folders, and it is not the primary reason for the slow networking. The reason for the slow networking is a bad autodetection of the network settings. You DO NOT want Windows to automatically detect settings when Virtualbox is installed. Go to Control Panel => Internet Properties => Connections tab => LAN settings, and make sure all of the checkboxes are UNchecked. After I did this and rebooted, the difference was night and day!